# Angular 1.5.3 & Typescript & ngComponentRouter : bindings: { $router:'<' } always returns undefined for router property

Tags: angularjs, ngcomponentrouter

I'm trying the component router for Angular 1.5.3 with typescript and classes for component controllers, but I fail to inject the current router in any of my components with bindings:{$router:'<'}. When I inspect $ctrl for any component in chrome debugger, it always shows undefined. The routing itself is working like expected (components are shown, routing link works, $routerOnActivate gets called). I need the $router to navigate from code.

The html page:

```
   <div ng-app="app">
        <app></app>
   </div>
```

The code

```
class AppCtrl {
}

var appComp: ng.IComponentOptions = {
    template: `App <ng-outlet></ng-outlet>`,
    $routeConfig: [
        { path: '/', name: 'List', component: 'listComp', useAsDefault: true },
        { path: '/new', name:'New', component:'newComp'}
    ],
    bindings: { $router: '<' },
    controller:AppCtrl
};

class ListCtrl {
    message = '';
    $routerOnActivate=() => {
        this.message = 'is activated';
    }
}

var listComp: ng.IComponentOptions = {
    template: `<div><h1>List : {{$ctrl.message}}</h1><a ng-link="['New']">new</a></div>`,
    bindings: { $router: '<' },
    controller: ListCtrl
};

class NewCtrl {
    message = '';
    $routerOnActivate = () => {
        this.message = 'New is activated';
    }
}

var newComp: ng.IComponentOptions = {
    template: `<div><h2>New : {{$ctrl.message}}</h2></div>`,
    bindings: { $router: '<' },
    controller: NewCtrl,
}


angular.module('app', ['ngComponentRouter'])
    .value('$routerRootComponent', 'app')
    .component('app', appComp)
    .component('listComp', listComp)
    .component('newComp', newComp)
    ;
```

Comment: Implementation looks correct, you should use `this.$router` inside component should work

Comment: That is the problemen : this.$router is undefined in every component.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in a plunjr please?

Comment: Apparently I was some older version of angular router... after updating the angular_1_router.js everything works fine...

Comment: Hurrey..you did it.. Cheers

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, using v0.2.0 of angular_1_router.js.  What version did you upgrade to?  A plunker of the issue I have is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/3RDGMVbnwTGgSJY1k2Zw?p=preview

Comment: Using npm install from instructions on angular site. Or straight from github

Answer (score 0):

Okay i haven't enough reputation to add a comment so i have to write it this way. I've had the same issue and realized that the $router is undefined in my "main" app component.

So i've used in the app entry point component the $rootRouter and in the child components I've used the "this.$router". This way it is working but i don't know if this is the expected behavior or if i'm doing something wrong...

I came to that solution when I've read in the angular documentation the following (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router):

> Each component has its own Router. Unlike in Angular 2, we cannot use
>   the dependency injector to get hold of a component's Router. We can
>   only inject the $rootRouter. Instead we use the fact that the
>   ng-outlet directive binds the current router to a $router attribute on
>   our component.

The app entry point "< app>< /app>" isn't inside an ng-outlet so maybe it is somehow related to that